# Combine old site and new site structures

Tags: apache, .htaccess, restful-architecture

I want to implement the following:

- New site structure, based on new directory path, new PHP framework, DB structure, and so on. The site should be reachable under http://www.mysite.com
- Some pages from an old structure should keep working. Old site structure should be available and stay in its old folder, say `/var/www/myoldsite`
- Generally speaking, when I call specific pages, say http://www.mysite.com/specificpage.php, the old site should be called, otherwise, only pages from new site should be availble.

How should I design that? In virtual host of apache? Or in a `.htaccess` file?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I undrestand it correctly, but

I would propose you your new site will be available under http://www.mysite.com/new

Put this into .htaccess file:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^\.php$ http://www.mysite.com/new/$1.php [R=301,L]
```

This will redirect all traffic to new site if not eist in old

Comment: ok,thanks for your hint. so at some stage, say after 6 months, i can kill old?

Comment: When you want to stop old site code, simply move folder /var/www/mynewsite to /var/www/oldsite and remove this .htaccess rule.Then all trafic will go to document root of "old" site, but now there will be "new" site files.